# How do I raise an issue with Google SDK?

Tags: google-drive-api

We have the problem (see also [Error opening Google Sheets with own app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631629/error-opening-google-sheets-with-own-app)), that we are not able to access Google Sheets, created with the new Google Sheets in XSLX format when we only have

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
```

scope (it works with 
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive/drive.readonly
).

It works with sheets created with the old Google Spreadsheet.

How do we raise an issue with Google (and see when the issue has been corrected)?

Comment: There is no public issues list. Google says post it here (which you've done) and you could also try duplicating it here https://plus.google.com/communities/107264319205603895037 and then hope that a passing devrel engineer takes pity on you.

Comment: There is one problem with this type of handling: You never know when the problem is supposed to be fixed (without testing every day), because nobody at Google will update the stackoverflow question (that's at least what happened to my other Google related issues).

Comment: totally agree. I have ugly workarounds and restrictions in functionality within my code that I don't know if I can ever remove